# Hive map data retrieval pulling null values

Tags: hive

I am newbie to hive, I am having issue with complex data map retrieval, when I try to retrieve particular key value pair, it is also pulling null from the record.

Describe of my table phone

```
name                    string                                      
ph                      map<string,int>
```

This is my query

```
select ph["yy"] from phone;
```

and this is my data

```
gua {"p":123456}
xxx {"yy":7987897}
```

The result after executing the query is

```
hive> select ph["yy"] from phone;      
OK
NULL
7987897
```

I am wondering why it is throwing null value .

Please help I would greatly appreciate it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is in-build. This is valid for Array type columns as well. To avoid NULLs use the WHERE clause.

-- Programming with Hive :

ARRAY indexing is 0-based, as in Java. Here is a query that selects the first element of the subordinates array:

```
hive> SELECT name, subordinates[0] FROM employees;
John Doe Mary Smith
Mary Smith Bill King
Todd Jones NULL
Bill King NULL
```

Note that referencing a nonexistent element returns NULL. Also, the extracted STRING values are no longer quoted!